Who first came up with the idea of ​a scheme in algebraic geometry?
At first, I thought that Alexander Grothendieck was the first to come up with the idea of ​​the scheme and established it, but when I found out that the idea of ​​the scheme existed even before Grothendieck came up with it and that it was established by Grothendieck.
so I started to wonder, who first came up with the idea of ​​Scheme. When Grothendieck mentioned the scheme in his autobiography Res, he said that he was a successor to Galois-Riemann-Hilbert. So, was it Hilbert who first came up with the idea of ​​the scheme?
